# Can you check which email address is registered to your account?

Tags: wallets

I've not checked my Stellar account for years and realise now it's been upgraded. I've logged in and going through the process of updating Stellars to Lumens. I get my secret and public keys for the Lumens, but to confirm it says it'll send an email to me, which I should copy the confirmation code from. I'm not getting any email. Is there an issue with the email server or could I have an incorrect email listed on my account? Any way of checking this?